# No logro conectar con mi base de datos de Hostinger. "(28000/1045): Access denied for user"

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo problemas de conexión con bases de datos exernas, esta vez he tratado de conectar mi app con el web hosting Hostinger.

He subido los ficheros php, y cuando he probado la conexión mediante Hurl.it me da todo ok:

> ```
> GET http://gimcana.esy.es/consulta2.php?clau=246&titol_pista=eeii
>
>    200 OK       2 bytes       348 ms
>
> View Request View Response
>
>  HEADERS
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Length: 22
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
> Date: Tue, 06 Jun 2017 22:20:23 GMT
> Server: Apache
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.21
> BODY
> ```

El fichero php que comunica con mysql en hostinger es:

```
function ejecutarSQLCommand($commando){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.es", "usuario", "clave", "base");
                         //Estos datos los modifiqué al publicar acá

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
    if ($resultset = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

        }
        $resultset->free();
    }
}
```

Al conectarme a http://gimcana.esy.es/consulta2.php?clau=246&titol_pista=eeii
me da el error:

> **Warning**: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'usuario'@'10.2.1.25' (using password: YES) in **/home/u766633572/public_html/functions2.php** on line **35**
>
> Connect failed: Access denied for user 'usuario'@'10.2.1.25' (using password: YES)

Comment: Abrí tu link y me dió lo siguiente: Access denied for user 'u766633572_mart2'@'10.2.1.25'  Seguramente el Usuario no está creado en la base de datos o no tiene los permisos necesarios, intenta con un root o agrega dicho usuario a través de phpmyadmin

Comment: ¿porque no pones tu comentario como respuesta?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que tienes la dirección correcta para conectarte? 10.2.1.25 es una IP de una red local y sería raro que fuera la que usas en el servidor online.

Comment: Trata de agregar el código que usas para conectarte a la base de datos (quitando el usuario y contraseña para que no lo vea todo el mundo), quizás encontremos así el problema. Tal y como está ahora, van a ser más conjeturas

Comment: Gracias, he añadido el fichero php que me pedís, gracias a todos!!

Comment: Insisto; el usuario no existe o no tiene permisos. Fijate en tu tabla usuarios de phpmyadmin

Comment: he logrado solucionar parcialmente mi problema cambiando el método GET por el metodo POST y funcionó!
Ahora me queda saber como mandar desde mi app con este método, ya que pasa los datos a la tabla por parámetros y no directamente desde la url...si alguién tiene alguna sugerencia... Gracias, de todos modos!

Comment: Amigo, en la seccion de bases de datos de el servidor de Hostinger, hay una opcion para autorizar IP Remotas para poder conectarte con el servidor de bases de datos; primero debes registrar esta IP, para que hostinger acepte su conexion...